# How do I run the Slack botkit on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, slack-api, slack

I am creating a new Slack botkit application and am having trouble with the install process.

Node.js and node-dependency are installed on my Windows 7 system properly.

https://github.com/howdyai/botkit

Then step 4, I run this command

```
c:\bot\botkit > token=REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_TOKEN node bot.js
(I replaced with my api key.)
```

In my command prompt it says this:

```
'token' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I think this for Linux or Mac command, so how do you operate it on Windows?

Comment: Why are you using an angle bracket?

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution:

```
c:\bot\botkit > set token=REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_TOKEN
```

Then:

```
c:\bot\botkit > node bot.js
```

It seems to work.

Angle brackets were not necessary.